# How to force closing HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, tcp, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpURLConnection in Android and I would like to know how to completely close it. There is disconnect function but in documentation I found that it not necessary closes connection. Indeed when I do:

```
adb shell netstat -lptu
```

I see my connection and disconnect does nothing. On the other hand if I close my app and remove it from "background" the connection is dissapears so I feel that there is a way.

I'm not interested in advices like "it's better to let connection reusing" because tests I need to pass are checking that connection was not closed and are failing. I can't modify test tools so I need to completely close the connection.

Comment: You also can't modify the (incorrect) way that Android implements `HttpURLConnection.disconnect().` So your test is what has to change here.

Comment: use keep-alive false